# CodeIgniter 3.x POST is empty

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm using the latest `CodeIgniter3.1` Version in my project. When I submit the form or use an AJAX call, I always get an empty `$this->input->post('XYZ')`. It works on my local machine, but not on the server.

The `csrf_protection` is set to FALSE and a `.htaccess` file does exist

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
 ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Here is my Form Code, it doesn't matter if i use "form_open" or use it directly like this, it only works on my local dev machine:

```
<form method="post" id="login_form" action="/index.php/login">
        <label for="email"><?php echo $this->lang->line('username'); ?> *</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="logfeld" autocomplete="username" />
        <label for="passwort"><?php echo $this->lang->line('password'); ?> *</label>
        <input type="password" name="passwort" id="passwort" class="logfeld" autocomplete="current-password" />
        <input class="sendbut" type="submit" name="login" value="<?php echo set_value('passwort'); ?>" />
    </form>
```

How can I fix that problem?

Comment: mention your local machine code

Comment: Can you post your form code here?

Comment: show us your controller code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you should use this method :

```
$pos = $this->input->post();
    if(isset($pos['XYZ']))$xyz = $pos['XYZ'];else $xyz='';
```

Comment: The $pos array and $pos['XYZ'] is always empty.

Comment: what me thod are you using for post method ?

Comment: i think the problems is in here `<form method="post" id="login_form" action="/index.php/login">` try change to
`<form method="post" id="login_form" action="/login">`